# Rigid body hair mesh clipping and collision issues

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation, hair, rigidbody

I'm completely stumped by rigid bodies and trying to figure out where I went wrong. I have rigged a series of hair braid objects using the [Wiggle Bone Add-On](https://blenderartists.org/t/wiggle-bones-a-jiggle-bone-implementation-for-2-8/1154726), which is a great way to get some natural, springy bounce when the hair moves. The trouble comes when I try to fix the collision issues that result.

With the help of another add-on, I've added rigid body cubes over each braid, and despite all of the braids having the same rigid body settings, only some work. The ones in the front are perfect, but the sides still clip the head sphere no matter what I do.

Also, why do my braids bounce around so much? I want them to be rigged to react to eventual animation, but at the moment even at rest with no motion or momentum, they immediately start bouncing around. How can I set them to be at rest until they are put into motion?

Thanks for your advice!

[my test blend file (it's easier to see with overlays turned off)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JbOsNMHa6pAa9bAf_ezQPIyePNz8EQKv/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think Luca rood figured out how to make a working version of hair collision. https://twitter.com/LucaRood/status/1214684493564596226 I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: That looks really promising! But I'll have to keep it in mind for next time, since my hair is already modeled and rigged as a mesh. I don't think I can benefit from the new collision update on this one if it's pure particles

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, adding more bones that better aligned with the finer details of each mesh seemed to solve the issue of why some collisions were working better than others. I noticed the bones were more or less adhering to the rigid body parameters, but visually it wasn't apparent because the braids attached to them weren't perfectly aligned.